# How to update user profile data for one to many relationship?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a database structure for artists. They have one-to-one name, lastname and other fields like follows:

**Table name:artists**

[image]

I created a genres table which consists of 4 possible genres that artists can perform: Classical, Hiphop, Jazz and Other.

**Table name: genres**

[image]

Each artist has a one-to-many relationship with genres:

**Table name: artist_genres**

[image]

To display the genres played by an artist I run the sql command:

```
$sql = "SELECT genre_id FROM artists JOIN artist_genres ON artists.id=artist_genres.artist_id";
$result = $database->query($sql);

  $newsql = "SELECT genre_name FROM genres WHERE id = $result"; //This is incorrect, but that's the logic
  $genrenames = $database-> query($newsql);
```

---

---

Now what I'm interested in is how to update the genres, when a user let's say decides to switch from both RAP and Other to Classical and Jazz. I can't think of an easy way to do it, all my attempts end up being very complicated.

I first try to check if artist_id already exists in the artist_genres table. If it does, I either run do_nothing(), delete (unsubscribed from genre) or insert (subscribed) depending on user choice. I was thinking of a function that uses if(isset(artist_id AND genre_id) , DELETE() else INSERT))

I'm currently using FORM checkboxes to give values to the genres. Is this efficient?

**UPDATE:**
I'm trying to do it in a object-orientated way. I created an object called Artistgenre, with functions to select genre_id's based on artist_id

Comment: By "a user decides to switch..." do mean something like "an artist changes their associated genres"?

Comment: @Uueerdo yes, precisely, or if they don't have genres associated with them at all, create them

Comment: What is wrong with adding and removing them one genre at a time? If you know what they had, you should know what needs removed.

Comment: So on update, we would remove all entries that they had using sql command, and then only INSERT new ones which they selected?

Comment: Remove the ones you know they had but that were deselected and add the ones they didn't have but had selected; if you want minimal table changes. Otherwise, you can just delete all for artist, and reinsert new (complete) set of choices.

Answer (score 1):

With this method, it is a bit more complicated to use parameterized queries (they don't take lists directly); but you can get it done in two queries.

```
DELETE 
FROM artist_genres 
WHERE artist_id = X 
   AND genre_id NOT IN ([current_list])
;

INSERT INTO artist_genres (artist_id, genre_id)
SELECT X, genre_id
FROM genres
WHERE genre_id IN ([current_list])
   AND genre_id NOT IN (
              SELECT genre_id 
              FROM artist_genres 
              WHERE artist_id = X
              )
;
```

The first query removes the associations no longer in the list, the second associates the genres in the list that not already associated.

Note: If genres is a very large table (doubtful), the INSERT...SELECT strategy may become too costly; but for relatively small tables like this, it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, I'll work with this. I am also wondering how to get [current list]? I'm using checkboxes like: <input type="checkbox" name="Genres[]" value="1">Classical<br> , so the $Genres = $_POST['Genres']$ would be the [current_list]? Assuming values are the genre_ids?

Comment: `[current_list]` is a place holder for a list you would generate from your controls/class; in an actual query `[current_list]` should look something like `3, 5, 2, 17`; or `?, ?, ?` in a parameterized query, with enough `?`'s for each value in your list (set as parameters).

Comment: Thanks, so the current_list is from the sql query SELECT genre_id WHERE artist_id = current artist, I then use bind($current_list) and store_result(); I'll be trying this out tomorrow, I will update you how I got on.

Comment: My php is not so great, but if "bind" is for parameterized queries, then: No, you cannot have a list as a parameter as far as I know; you have to parameterize each element of the list.